# download mutliple files with wget on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, download, wget

I am trying to download 50 pdf's from a webserver using wget on windows. All pdf's reside in www.abc.com/files/ and their url's are (www.abc.com/files/x.pdf, where x = 1,2,3...50 )

the batch script I have written is

```
set "directory = http://www.abc.com/files/"
for %%x in (1, 1, 50) do (
        set pdfNum = %%x
    set "num = %directory%%pdfNum%"
        set "pdf = .pdf"
        set "file = %num%%pdf%"
    wget file
)
```

but it doesn't seems to work.Help anyone. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3):

```
for /L %%x in (1,1,50) do (
        wget http://www.abc.com/files/%%x.pdf
)
```

This code could help u.

Comment: thanks, i didn't know this way of string concatenation in dos,but can you please correct my code.

Answer (score 2):

you have some errors there... the way to do it is:

```
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 @echo off
 set directory=courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec/
 for /l %%x in (1, 1, 50) do (
    set pdfNum=%%x
    set num=%directory%!pdfNum!
    set pdf=.pdf
    set file=!num!%pdf%
    wget !file!
 )
```

- you must not have spaces in the `set param=value` line
- `for /l` iterates though the numbers

but i noticed that http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec/1.pdf doesn't exist (i checked 1, 2, 3, 10 ... and i can't access them. besides that it works for me

Comment: not working... .if i do file_name.bat > log.txt,it gives C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop>for /L %x in (1 1 50) do (
set pdfNum=%x  
 set num=28    
 set pdf=.pdf    
 set file=50.pdf    
 wget .pdf 
)

Comment: ya,i have updated the directory variable but that would have given "Not found" error. now,it's showing "Missing url"

Comment: so can you write your set directory=... line? (i want to see how it looks like)

Comment: set directory=http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec. you need to change range in for loop to (10, 1, 25)

Comment: @eyossi: The problem with your script is that all environment variables in the body of the loop are evaluated before the loop is executed. You need to enable and use delayed expansion.

Comment: @AndriyM You're right!, i didn't have to use it before but now it makes sense... thank you!
Abhi - check now

Comment: @eyossi, see my comment.you need to change range in for loop. for /l %%x in (10,1,25). Upto 10, their names are ..../01.pdf, ..../02.pdf. so try with (10, 1, 25)

Comment: @abhi120 i need to change it? you have the answer right there, change it according to your range you need

Comment: @eyossi,still not working. If it's working on your side ,try with range(10, 1, 25). ( and .../10.pdf, .../11/pdf upto /25.pdf exists )

Comment: @eyossi,sorry my fault.it was /lec10.pdf not /lec/10.pdf.  http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec10.pdf exists